# Github actions: Unable to install private GPR npm package

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions

I've been having some issues installing a scoped package that that was published to GPR

See below for my actions file

```yaml
name: run unit and coverage tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com/'
        scope: '@OWNER'
    - name: Authenticate with GitHub package registry
      run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com:_authToken=${{ secrets.PRIVATE_ACCESS_TOKEN }}" > ~/.npmrc
    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm ci
        npm run test:unit
        npm run lint
        npm run test:e2e -- --headless
      env:
        CI: true
```

my .npmrc file is as follows:

`@discoveryedu:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/`

my private access token has *read:packages*, *write:packages*, and *repo* privileges.

I'm getting the following error in actions:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@owner/repo/version/hash
```

i've subbed the *owner*, *repo*, and *version* names for privacy.

Comment: same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124831/github-actions-401-unauthorized-when-installing-a-github-package-with-npm-or-ya?noredirect=1

Comment: @StephenSylvester There is an answer to the question linked by MLyck, that should solve your problem as you also forgot the second backslash after the url: ` echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=..` instead of ` echo "//npm.pkg.github.com:_authToken=...`.