# How can I publish a private github package with github actions inside a private organization repo?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-package-registry

I have a private repo inside my free github organization. When I try to publish a private package to Github Packages with Actions, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@organization%2ftailwind - Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
```

my github action `main.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
name: Node.js Package

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      
jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
          scope: '@organization'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: $({secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN})
```

and my `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "@organization/tailwind",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Package Description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@organization"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/organization/tailwind.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/organization/tailwind/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/organization/tailwind#readme"
}
```

What do I need to change to get this working? I also tried to use a personal access token with read/write packages permissions from my github account but this also doesn't work.

Comment: I would say that the token does not have enough permissions to perform the task as the error message says. You can create a new token and set the necessary permissions yourself. The procedure is described in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#permissions-for-the-github_token).

Comment: @flaxel it doesn't work. I created a new personal access token with read, write package permissions, but i get the same error...

Comment: Your problem looks similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124831/github-actions-401-unauthorized-when-installing-a-github-package-with-npm-or-yarn

Comment: @Niklas - Did you manage to resolve your issue? If yes, how did you resolve it. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
   },
```

My working configuration does not include my organization name in the registry.